# Compactness of the set of functions from a compact set to a finite set

Tags: compactness

Let $(K,\mathcal{B},P)$ be a probability space where $K$ is a **compact** set, $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel sigma-algebra and P is a Borel probability measure. Let $A$ be an arbitrary **finite** set.

Consider the space of measurable functions from $K$ to $A$, endowed with the following metric: for every $f,g \in A^K$ $d(f,g)=P(\{k \in K:f(k)\neq g(k)\})$. Is this set compact? If yes, why? If not, can you provide a counterexample?

Comment: What do you think? How does the hypothesis that $K$ is compact help you?